Horizon problem and the infinite whole universe
So I understand that inflation makes the universe expand so rapidly that all points on the CMB were within the horizon and thus in causal contact. However, the horizon calculated with inflation is still a finite number, then doesn't this mean outside that scale in other parts of the universe, beyond our observable universe, things were never in causal contact and thus may have different temperatures than our 2.7K? But then doesn't this violate the cosmological principle of homogeneity?

Yes the universe could be structured on scales larger than those we can observe.
The fact that the universe is close to homogeneous on very large scales (but within the scales we can observe) is an empirical observation, but it could easily have been otherwise, e.g. having structure on all scales. There is no logical or mathematical reason to prefer the homogenous case a priori, so that is NOT what the cosmological principle (correctly formulated) is doing. What the cosmological principle is meant to do is advance the reasonable hypothesis that the solar system is not at a special place in the cosmos. But really that hypothesis does very little, if any, explanatory work. For if the cosmos is homogenous then there isn't a special place in it anyway, and if the cosmos is not homogenous then for all we know the special character of the Milky Way (namely that it contains life) may require it to be at a special place (e.g. on the trunk of a tree-like structure, or a leaf, or something like that).
I think the only thing this kind of reasoning offers us is that if the universe looks isotropic from our viewpoint, then it is entirely reasonable to state that this is most likely because it is homogeneous (and therefore isotropic from all viewpoints). This is an empirical observation and it does not tell us about scales above that of the observable universe.


ABC asked: "Doesn't this mean outside that scale in other parts of the universe, beyond our observable universe, things were never in causal contact and thus may have different temperature?"

Inflation could solve the flatness, horizon and singularity problems since a closed universe with exponential expansion starts with a zero Hubble parameter and a nonzero size, see here and here.
Then the Hubble parameter rose and converged to a constant value which lead to exponential expansion until the end of inflation, so at the start of the inflation the comoving Hubbleradius shrunk so that everything within your present (comoving) Hubbleradius was also inside the much larger past Hubbleradius, so everything you see had the chance to interact with each other while the Hubble parameter was small in the beginning.
Whether or not there are objects outside our current observable universe which never had the chance to interact with each other depends on the model:

In the standard big bang model without inflation not everything outside our current observable universe  could have interacted with each other in the past.

If you assume the universe had inflation and started with the Planck density and the Planck length then everything in the whole (closed) universe could have interacted with each other in the beginning.

If you assume the initial density smaller and the initial radius of curvature larger then there might as well be objects outside our current observable universe that never interacted with each other in the past.


The lower bounds for the inflation (around 60 e-folds during the inflation) are chosen such that at least all objects inside our current observable universe could have interacted with each other in the beginning, but we don't how high exactly it was, it could as well have been higher, assuming that there even was an inflation, which not everyone believes in:

Roger Penrose wrote: "Inflation isn't falsifiable, it's falsified. ... BICEP did a wonderful service by bringing all the inflation-ists out of their shell, and giving them a black eye."

